# How do I most easily access a specific field in a .NET PE-file?

Tags: c#, .net, executable, portability

I'm making a program that should compare two files of the Portable Executable format, to see if they were compiled from the same code. There are fields that always will differ, even when the code wasn't changed. My solution is basically to load the files into my program and set all timestamps and checksums to zero and then compare them. This works fine for exe-files, but .NET DLL's also have a revision field in the #~ stream which is much harder to access. I'd have to parse all headers which seems quite tedious and I'd be happy if I could avoid doing that.

Now I'm thinking about just ignoring the whole #~ stream. Can I do this and still be sure the files are equivalent? It feels like a waste of time to read in all headers when I just need the address of one field. If i cannot do this, could you suggest other less time-consuming solutions?

Could add that I'm programming in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Mono Cecil? It's a great API for reading and modifing .NET assemblies.

see http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil